# What does the idiom "hue and cry" mean?

Tags: word-usage, idioms

My chief used the idiom *hue and cry* when he addressed us in his inaugural talk.

Googling gave me this meaning:

> Not to make an issue

But I don't fully understand what that means. Can anyone explain it and its usage to me?

Comment: the idiom can be used in many ways. It could be 'hue and cry' about your chief's addressing as well! :)

Comment: hue (n.2) "a shouting," mid-13c., from Old French hue "outcry, noise, war or hunting cry," probably of imitative origin. Hue and cry is late 13c. as an Anglo-French legal term meaning "outcry calling for pursuit of a felon." Extended sense of "cry of alarm" is 1580s. ---> http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=hue&searchmode=none

Answer (score 3):

A "hue and cry" was originally a loud shout after a criminal ("Stop Thief!") to alert others nearby to chase after them and catch them.

Now, it usually means a public ruckus about something that may or may not be criminal or illegitimate. There could be a "hue and cry" about the AC making the building too cold for example. It could even just be a loud gossip and pity party that doesn't really mean to be productive or solve the problem the members are complaining about.

Answer (score 1):

"Hue and cry" is a fuss, probably out of proportion to its goals. It's noisy, perhaps a bit obnoxious. The fuss is intended to make a point, but if it's being referred to as a "hue and cry", the point is probably being lost in the dramatics of the whole ting.